# How do you run an eclipse rcp application on linux?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, neo4j

Sorry if this is a dumb question but for the life of me I can't figure out how to run this eclipse rcp application (https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse/downloads) on ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that your computer has a 32-bit Intel or AMD processor.

- You'll be using a terminal such as Gnome Terminal.
- First make sure some "java" program is available by typing "which java". If not, install openjdk, or some equivalent if you know which one you want.
- Then download neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86.zip, perhaps via "curl -L https://github.com/downloads/neo4j/neoclipse/neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86.zip > neoclipse-1.6.linux.gtk.x86.zip"
- "unzip neoclipse-1.6.linux.gtk.x86.zip"
- "chmod u+x neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86/neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86/neoclipse".
- "neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86/neoclipse-1.6-linux.gtk.x86/neoclipse".

If some part of these instructions presents a difficulty, please clarify.